# Mysql drops connetion after some long time

Tags: mysql, node.js

Mysql drops the connection when its connected for a long time in nodejs.

I have nodejs bot that reads some requests from a api, then writes those to mysql db, but if there is no data comes in 7-8 hours it drops the connection... what should i do im using nodejs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL [wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) is what you are looking for. From the documentation:

> The number of seconds the server waits for activity on a
>   noninteractive connection before closing it.

By default, this is set as 8 hours